# how to handle exception in middleware laravel?

Tags: laravel, cors

I am using `Barryvdh` package for cross origin for API's in Laravel.
In some API I am using `dd` function explicitly.
When I used `dd` function then it show me an error for cross origin.
I have searched on this, some says that it does not return header in `dd` function case. When I saw this handle function within middleware, I have seen this:

```
$response = $next($request);
return $this->cors->addActualRequestHeaders($response, $request);
```

What should I do to handle this scenarios.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is a bad practice to use `dd()` as a real response. Why don't you just return the object instead.

Answer (score 0):

`dd` stands for `debug dump` as Thomas mentions this function should not end up in production code because what it does is `var_dump` and then `exit`. This forces your application code to be killed and force output to your browser.

If you want to force a response you should create a normal Response object, eg `Illuminate\Http\Response` or use any of the helpers, eg `abort()` or `response()`.

References:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-abort
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-response

Comment: actually i had to add cors package for laravel and i am changing in already build project in whole project old developer use if validation fails then 
"die($this->validationErrors($validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));".
so if use abort or response then i have to change in many changes.

Comment: That's what an ide is for?